# How do I append the following firebase data to the userData dictionary?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The data gets printed correctly, but I don't know how to store it in a single variable to use elsewhere. Any help appreciated.

```swift
class HomeViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {

  @Published var userData: [UserInfo] = []

  func getUserData() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    let doc = db.collection("users").document(userID)

    doc.getDocument { document, error in
      if let document = document, document.exists {
        let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"

        print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")

      } else {
        print("document does not exist")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct UserInfo: Identifiable {
  var id: String
  var name: String
  var email: String
  var password: String
  var uid: String
}
```

Comment: This would probably be beneficial reading: https://peterfriese.dev/posts/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use Codable to map your data, just like @jnpdx recommended. As for making the data available in a single location that can be accessed across your app, consider using an `@StateObject` at the root of your app, and then making it available via the environment. LMK if you'd like to see a full answer for this approach.

Comment: Could you please show the full answer of how you'd approach this? @PeterFriese. I read your guide, but it's beyond the scope of what I understand.

Comment: @Alex - would love to understand how to improve my blog post / explanations - can you tell me which parts you find hard to understand?

Also, feel free to share a [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with me via a gist or private GitHub repo, and I am happy to make the required changes and explain how it works.